# JavaFX Combobox List Styling

Tags: java, css, javafx, combobox

I'm trying to change the text color of a JavaFX combobox list but it does not seem to work.

```
.combo-box .list-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-my-menu-font-color-highlighted;
}
.combo-box-popup .list-view{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-my-menu-color;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell{
    -fx-text-fill: #ff0000;
    -fx-padding: 4 0 4 5;
    -fx-background-color: -fx-my-menu-color;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:selected, .combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:selected:hover{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-my-menu-color-highlighted;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-my-menu-font-color-highlighted;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:hover{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-my-menu-color-highlighted;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-my-menu-font-color-highlighted;
}

.combo-box-base{
    -fx-background-color: -fx-my-menu-color;
    -fx-padding: 0;
}
```

This returns the following:
The Dropdown list text is not white

[image]

How do I fix this? My CSS knowledge is not very strong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example below should work fine - if not, remove other entries from your CSS which could affect the popop list as well. Possibly another entry has higher priority.

```
.combo-box-popup .list-cell {    
    -fx-background-color: white;    
    -fx-text-fill: red;
}
```

to increase the specificity you can also try the setting below

```
.combo-box-popup > .list-view > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet > .list-cell {
        -fx-background-color: white;    
        -fx-text-fill: red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! It works :) I had to add another line of code in the class though.

Comment: Where is the reference to this class hiraracy ?